# nodejs socket.io emit inside function loop

Tags: node.js, loops, socket.io, emit

I would like to emit through socket.io inside a loop. For that I made a trigger which works well, but at each trig I call socket.emit and only the first emit works.

Here is the server code :

```
var server = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var fs = require('fs');
var ee = require('events').EventEmitter;
var trig = new ee();

server.listen(8080);

function handler(req,res){
    fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(content);
        console.log('page affichée');
    }); 
}

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('run',function(v){
        run(v);
    });
    trig.on('node',function(i){
        io.sockets.emit('node',i);
        console.log(i);
    });
});

function run(v){
    for(i=0;i<v;i++){
        trig.emit('node',i+1);
    }
}
```

and here is the client code :

```
<input id='file' type='text'></input>
<input type='button' value='lancer le process' onclick="socket.emit('run',document.getElementById('file').value);"></input>
<script>

        var compt_nod = document.getElementById('compteur_nodes');

        socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080/');

        socket.on('node',function(v){
            compt_nod.value = v;
            console.log(v);
        });
</script>
```

I got the log from the server, but only the first answer on the client side. I'm quite new in JS and especialy in Node, so apologize for this maybe simple question.

Comment: You never emit (client-side) `run`, so the code in the server when a client emits `run` will not be executed so your `run` function will also not be run (and the loop won't loop).