# Server process progress over Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, socket.io, progress-bar

I'm trying to display a progress bar in the front end for a process that happens on the server. I'm trying to send progress update messages over websockets(**SocketIO**) using emits but the problem that I am facing is that they all come together at the same time when differents loops finished, rather than as they are emitted.

This is, really simplified, the code I'm using.

```
//Server side function
functionThatShouldEmitInTime(data){
    readFileWithCallback(data, function(dataUpdated){
        readFileWithCallback(dataUpdated, function(dataEvenMoreUpdated){
            var w = dataEvenMoreUpdated.w;
            for (var c in w) {
                for (var e in c){
                    var to_be_filled;
                    //Do stuff
                    for (var a in e) {
                        //do stuff with to_be_filled
                        for(var pr in a){
                            //do stuff with to_be_filled
                            for(var pe i pr){
                                //do stuff with to_be_filled
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    writeFileAsync(to_be_filled);
                    console.log(to_be_filled.name + ' is being written');
                    socket.emit('file:processed', 'type_of_file');
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
```

This works fine, only that the emits, are sent when all loops end. Therefore the progress in the client is displayed instantly and at the end of the operation. Not gradually as it goes happening.

I try to force node to emit with the following modification. Using **process.nextTick();**

```
//Server side function
functionThatShouldEmitInTime(data){
    readFileWithCallback(data, function(dataUpdated){
        readFileWithCallback(dataUpdated, function(dataEvenMoreUpdated){
            var w = dataEvenMoreUpdated.w;
            for (var c in w) {
                for (var e in c){
                    var to_be_filled;
                    //Do stuff
                    for (var a in e) {
                        //do stuff with to_be_filled
                        for(var pr in a){
                            //do stuff with to_be_filled
                            for(var pe i pr){
                                //do stuff with to_be_filled
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    writeFileAsync(to_be_filled);
                    console.log(to_be_filled.name + ' is being written');
                    process.nextTick(force_emit);
                }
            }
        });
    });
};

function force_emit() {
    socket.emit('file:processed', 'type_of_file');
}
```

I also read and tried all the information in this StackOverflow posts but without success:

[Sending Multiples Emits Inside a Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852972/sending-multiple-emits-inside-a-loop)

[Nodejs SocketIO Emit Function Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309886/nodejs-socket-io-emit-inside-function-loop)

[SocketIo Emit in Loop Until Client Responds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086991/socket-io-emit-in-loop-until-client-responds)

[SocketIo Inside Loop Does Not Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898258/socket-io-inside-of-loop-doesnt-work)

I will like to know if there is a work around or a better way to implements this.

Answer (score 0):

As by name writeFileAsync is a async function, so whenever async returns in 
callback emit the events, to truly show the progress.

Comment: I already did that, I mean, emit inside the writeFileAsync function, but the result is the same.

Comment: As all writeFileAsync calls will run parallely, thus they might be finishing around same time, thus emitting socket event around same time. Could you try running writeFileAsync in series and check whether still all event comes at same time.

Comment: Thanks for the directions, I was able to solve the problem using async library, using series instead of run all process in parallel.   async.eachOfSeries(data, function(item, key, callback){ functionThatShouldEmitInTime(){....CODEHERE... callback();}});

Comment: More about this in this post. https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/261